# How to convert string to date to string in Swift iOS?

Tags: ios, string, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Am learning swift and am struck in converting the date String to NSDate to string. Am getting the date string in this format "Thu, 22 Oct 2015 07:45:17 +0000". I need to show the date in the MM-dd-yyyy format. I tried the following code but, it returns "null".

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
let dateObj = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString!)
print("Dateobj: \(dateObj)")
```

Can anyone please help where am going wrong? Looking forward the help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: read this document if any one want to know about the date formate http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Answer (score 116, accepted):

First, you need to convert your string to NSDate with its format. Then, you change the `dateFormatter` to your simple format and convert it back to a String.

**Swift 3**

```
let dateString = "Thu, 22 Oct 2015 07:45:17 +0000"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss +zzzz"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "en_GB")

let dateObj = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
print("Dateobj: \(dateFormatter.string(from: dateObj!))")
```

The printed result is: `Dateobj: 10-22-2015`

Comment: In `Swift 3` is quite similar, instead of `dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)` is `dateFormatter.string(from:date)`.

Comment: This will crash if your device is not in english because of "Thu", you have to specify the locale. In swift 3 : `dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "en_GB")`

Comment: NSDateFormatter has been replaced with DateFormatter

Comment: NOTE: This answer is incorrect if the date should be localized. For example in various countries month and day are swapped

Comment: This is using the wrong locale. You need to use `en_US_POSIX` when using the date formatter to convert a fixed format string into a `Date`.

Comment: @Gargo This is a great example of why you should never use `dateFormat` to convert a `Date` into a string presented to a user. Always use `dateStyle` and `timeStyle`.

Answer (score 51):

```
//String to Date Convert

var dateString = "2014-01-12"
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let s = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
println(s)


//CONVERT FROM NSDate to String  

let date = NSDate()
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd" 
var dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
println(dateString)
```

Answer (score 8):

Swift 2 and below

```
let date = NSDate()
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
var dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
println(dateString)
```

And in Swift 3 and higher this would now be written as:

```
let date = Date()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
var dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
```

Comment: this is converting from a date to a string

Answer (score 4):

See answer from Gary Makin. And you need change the format or data. Because the data that you have do not fit under the chosen format. For example this code works correct:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
let dateObj = dateFormatter.dateFromString("10 10 2001")
print("Dateobj: \(dateObj)")
```