# iOS Swift 3 : Convert "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" format string to date object

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

Hello i have a dictionary

```
self.publishedAt = dictionary["publishedAt"] as? NSString
```

in which i'm getting date "**2017-01-27T18:36:36Z**". I want to convert it in
readable format : **dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss**. i tried via

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: (self.publishedAt as? String)!)
print("EXACT_DATE : \(date)")
```

But getting nil. :(

What is the correct way to get date in simple format?

Comment: You need an **input** format to convert the ISO8601 string to date and an **output** format to convert the date back to string, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33277970/how-to-convert-string-to-date-to-string-in-swift-ios?rq=1, And don't use `NSString` in Swift.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You need an input format to convert the ISO8601 string to date and an output format to convert the date back to string:

```
let string = "2017-01-27T18:36:36Z"

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
let tempLocale = dateFormatter.locale // save locale temporarily
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") // set locale to reliable US_POSIX
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: string)!
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.locale = tempLocale // reset the locale
let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
print("EXACT_DATE : \(dateString)")
```

Comment: @vadian Why do you reset the locale?

Comment: @user1960169 As mentioned in Rob's answer please read [Apple Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1480/_index.html)

Comment: I'm getting `Thread7: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional Value`. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: @JkAlombro The string doesn't match the date format. It must be **exactly** the format as in the answer

Comment: EXACT_DATE : 28/01/2017 it suppose to get 27/01/2023

Answer (score 17):

To convert string to `Date` object:

```
let string = "2017-01-27T18:36:36Z"
let isoFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
let date = isoFormatter.date(from: string)!
```

Or, if you need to support iOS versions that predate [`ISO8601DateFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/iso8601dateformatter):

```
let isoFormatter = DateFormatter()
isoFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX"
isoFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
isoFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
let date = isoFormatter.date(from: string)!
```

(To understand why we set the `locale` for the ISO 8601 date formatter, see [Apple Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480).)

Then, to convert that to a user-friendly date format, you'd use a separate formatter (or use the second example, above, you can re-use the formatter, but remember to reset the `locale` back to `Locale.current`):

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = .short
formatter.timeStyle = .medium
let result = formatter.string(from:date)
```

Note, I'd suggest using those style parameters when presenting the date back to the user rather than the `dateFormat` string, so it's using the styles appropriate for their locale, rather than assuming they want 24h clock or not and/or whether they use `dd-MM-yyyy` vs `MM-dd-yyyy` format.

---

Note, changing the formats of date formatter (e.g. changing the `dateFormat` string) is a relatively expensive process, so if you're performing this process for multiple dates, do not take a single `DateFormatter` and constantly change its `dateFormat` or styles repeatedly back and forth (or worse, instantiate new formatters for each date). Instead, create one formatter per date format style and re-use it grammar as much as possible.

Answer (score 4):

Just used the function in your code(swift 4.2).

```
public func convertDateFormatter(date: String) -> String {

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"//this your string date format
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC") as TimeZone!
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "your_loc_id")
let convertedDate = dateFormatter.date(from: date)

guard dateFormatter.date(from: date) != nil else {
    assert(false, "no date from string")
    return ""
}
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm a"///this is what you want to convert format
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC") as TimeZone!
let timeStamp = dateFormatter.string(from: convertedDate!)
print(timeStamp)
return timeStamp
}
```

Thanks