# Converting a date to a (non human-readable) string in Swift 3

Tags: swift, date, swift3, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a Date object, like so:

```
 2017-06-08 08:36:16 +0000
```

I need to convert this to a string, in this form:

```
"2017-06-08T08:36:16Z"
```

The REST api I am posting to only accepts dates as strings.

Most info I find online is about converting dates to human readable formats. If possible, I could probably even just "stringify" my date object, however trying to cast it as such obviously fails. There are tons of "convert date to string" questions out there, but haven't ran across any like this yet.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: How is `"2017-06-08T08:36:16Z"` a "non human-readable" string? – What prevents you from using a `DateFormatter`?

Comment: probably just reverse of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41907419/ios-swift-3-convert-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmssz-format-string-to-date-object?rq=1)

Comment: @MartinR sorry it was confusing. I meant it as in, most questions like this want a string output like "June 7, 2017" (something you may output to a user), where as you would rarely (if ever) output "2017-06-08T08:36:16Z" to a user.

Comment: Have a look at this page: http://nsdateformatter.com It is a good reference when "designing" your `dateFormat` strings :)

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is changing the date format ([DateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter)) to the desired one.

Note that the *format* of your given date (`2017-06-08 08:36:16 +0000`) is:

> yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z

For instance, consider that the given date value is today, you could read it -as a string- like this:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"

let givenDate = Date()
let stringGivenDate = dateFormatter.string(from: givenDate) // 2017-06-08 12:10:23 +0300
```

thus, changing the date format to:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:SS'Z'"
let stringGivenDateWithDesiredFormat = dateFormatter.string(from: givenDate) // 2017-06-08T12:11:75Z
```

As per the code snippet above, your given desired format (`2017-06-08T08:36:16Z`) is:

> yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:SS'Z'

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:SS'Z'"
let dateDate =  NSDate()
let stringDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date as Date)
```

Where `date` is your Date object in `2017-06-08 08:36:16 +0000` format

Answer (score 2):

Following two formats will work for you.
`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z`
and `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'`

```
let input = "2017-06-08 08:36:16 +0000"
let dateFormater = DateFormatter.init()
dateFormater.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"
if let date = dateFormater.date(from: input) {
    dateFormater.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
    let output = dateFormater.string(from: date)
    print(output)
}
```