# Dateformat of 2017-12-16T07:28:59.629Z

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

What date format I need to process this string? `2017-12-16T07:28:59.629Z`

Tried `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ` and Tried `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sssZZZZZ`

Anyway how many `s` and `Z` needs end of the format?

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sssZZZZZ"
date = dateFormatter.date(from: value as! String)
```

Comment: Have a look to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41907419/ios-swift-3-convert-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmssz-format-string-to-date-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the dateformat as

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
```

as the [Date Format Patterns](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns) suggests that **"S"** is the format specifier for **fractions of seconds**.