# Convert String date to Date doesn't work using dateFormatter and Swift

Tags: swift, date

This question **is not** a copy of another: I have an issue that I don't find somewhere else.

I want to convert a date as `String` to the `Date` format. This `String` date is supposed to be the same format as `Date` because I used to upload it as String in a database. Here is what the `String` date looks like:

"2017-03-10 22:16:00 +0000";

I'm trying to convert it like that:

```
    let df: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()

    df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss Z"

    print(beginDateString) // "2017-03-10 22:16:00 +0000"

    let beginDate = df.date(from: beginDateString)

    print(beginDate) // App crashs here because of nil value.
```

The issue is that it gives me a nil value for the variable `beginDate`.
I also tried with other `dateFormat` like this one: `"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Change hh to HH and you able to get date.

Comment: I already tried this that's why this question IS NOT a dublicate!

Comment: Have you tried format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z`

Comment: yes i'm using `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"`

Comment: In addition, you should set the locale to "POSIX", see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25657123/swift-nsdateformatter-not-working.

Comment: @greenpoisononeTV You will get date with format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z` not the nil.

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33278377/7671686). I think it will help you .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z` not `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss Z`.

Because `hh` for ***hour in am/pm (1~12).***

You also can do with: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss xxxx` or `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss XXXX`, etc.

[Read more](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime)

Comment: `hh is for (01-12)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
let beginDateString: String = "2017-03-10 22:16:00 +0000"
let df: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()

df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"

if let beginDate = df.date(from: beginDateString)
{
    print(beginDate) 
}
```

And as @javimuu said you have to change your template.